# Can a proportion confidence interval be thought of as error of estimation?

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion

One interpretation of a confidence interval for a mean is that the most plausible position of the mean (given no more information) is in the middle of the confidence interval, and the plausibility reduces in a normal curve with mean at the center of the confidence interval.

Can proportion confidence intervals be viewed in the same way? Or in another way that reflects error of estimation?

I'm guessing that this might be true for the normal approximation, but what about the 'exact' method?

Comment: This symmetry property is peculiar only to a few confidence interval procedures under very special circumstances.  It is not part of the defining properties of confidence intervals, nor is it true of many common CIs (such as for odds ratios in logistic regression, to name just one common application).  Because "proportion confidence interval" does not have a definite meaning--*what procedure is being used to compute the interval?*--this question isn't really answerable as asked.

Comment: @whuber well I did add that I guessed it might be true for the normal approximation method, and questioned about the 'exact' method. I guess the question would be 'to what extent could it be true for any method?'. The original source for this is Geoff Cummings' book: The New Statistics, and a summary can be found here: http://www.uncw.edu/psy/news/documents/Cumming-The%20New%20Statistics-PS-2014.pdf See page 17, or PDF page 12.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to an expert in this area, and he suggests that there's no reason he can see of not using that interpretation.

The one major difference with proportions is the discreteness.

Comment: I'm afraid that referring to unnamed "experts" doesn't meet minimal standards of objective support for an answer.  Do you have a reference to authoritative literature or an objective argument to back this up?

Comment: @whuber thanks. I thought that would be a problem -- I don't want to ask the person to give permission. This answer should probably be removed, and I perhaps should have put it in a comment